# Find Asp.net Web Forms control in script in Js (JavaScript) file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, aspx-user-control

I have the following script in a Web Forms project:

```
function myScriptInAspxFile() {
         var obj = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
         if (obj) {                 
             obj.value = "My Text";                 
         }
     }
```

this works fine when I put the script inside the Web forms aspx file, but when I change the script to a Js (JavaScript) file the line:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
```

The assignment returns me a null value for the obj variable. How could I find a control from a script in a Js (JavaScript) file? Greetings and thank you in advance.

Comment: `("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>")` this is an invalid way to find an element in JS, `getElementById` should have a _string_ with no spaces in between. also js will not understand what does `TextBox1.ClientID` is, unless it's in a `aspx` page.

Comment: @MHDAlaaAlhaj - the clue is `asp.net`

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540217/passing-variable-from-asp-net-to-javascript

Comment: What is the `ID` of `TextBox1` - you could use something like `document.querySelector("[id$=whateverTheIDis]")`

Comment: try declaring a variable in your js like this `const id = "<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>";` then `console.log(id)`, if you get your value correctly, then you can use `document.getElementById(id);`

Comment: @MHDAlaaAlhaj - that would assume the ASP.net `ID=` isn't *mangled* - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039/how-can-i-use-a-traditional-html-id-attribute-with-an-asp-net-runat-server-tag

Comment: Because the .js file does not run any server-side code, it cannot have any <% %> tags within it.  Therefore, you need to employ some method, such as what is suggested in the couple of other comments people have made.  Eg. either declare and set a variable (with the control's ID) within your .aspx page - and you can then reference that variable in your .js file.  Or perhaps use a hidden field, set the value to your control's ID, and in your .js file get the value from the hidden field that you can then use in getElementById

Comment: as long as your TextBox1 is directly on the Form and not within something like  `asp:Content` or `asp:Panel`, then try giving your TextBox1 an attribute of `ClientIDMode="Static"` and then try `document.getElementById("TextBox1");` .. other responses are correct, asp.net cannot rewrite your js file directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of course is that you wishing to have a hard coded text box name, and then use a external .js file. External files don't get nor enjoy server side expression processing.

There are two approaches here:

Use clientidMode="static" for the text box.

Hence this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >
        </asp:TextBox>
```

And now your js code becomes this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
```

Another approach?

Place BOTH the control and JavaScript inside of a user control.

So, say this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    function mytest() {
        var tBox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>')
        alert(tBox.value)
    }

</script>
```

Now, our markup becomes this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show text box value"
            OnClientClick="mytest();return false"
            />
             <br />

        <uc1:MyScriptControl runat="server" id="MyScriptControl" />
```

And the result is this:

[image]

You can also of course place some small js code stubs in the current page that calls/uses/enjoys the external .js library of code, but you thus have to "pass" the control value with smaller code stubs in the current page.

So, say this:

```
   <script>

        function mytestlocal() {
            var obj = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
            mytest(obj)
        }
   </script>
```

And thus in the external file we have this:

```
  function mytest(tBox) {
    alert(tBox.value)
}
```

So, the "very" idea of a external .js file means that external file can't have hard code controls, nor can it use or have <%=%> (server side) expressions.